# Getting Error " wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Tags: package-management, mount, compiling, nfs

I am running:

```
sudo mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /mnt/huge
```

Getting the following error:

```
mount: /mnt/huge: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I have run `apt install nfs-common` but I still get the same error.

#### Logs

```
# apt install nfs-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nfs-common is already the newest version (1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python3-gst-1.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 240 not upgraded.
```

```
# ls -l /sbin/mount.cifs
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35600 Mar 29  2018 /sbin/mount.cifs
```

```
# dpkg -l cifs-utils
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
ii  cifs-utils                    2:6.8-1             amd64               Common Internet File System utilities
```

```
# sudo mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /mnt/huge
mount: /mnt/huge: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the hugelbfs pages are available to use. Please take a look here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~nhall/shore-mt/onlinedoc/hugetlbfs.html

Comment: Hi Matthew, I tried it, but unfortunately I configured with wrong huge page size and and now I have to format entire system. Do you have any link which will explain these steps in easy way ?

Comment: @Rohitkamble  Hi,   I updated my answer, Does it work?